# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Tags: python, pandas

```
def date_convert(date_to_convert):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_convert,'%d/%m/%Y')

df['Date de la valeur'] = df['Date de la valeur'].apply(date_convert)
df["Date d'échéance"] = df["Date d'échéance"].apply(date_convert)

df['maturite'] = df["Date d'échéance"]-df['Date de la valeur']


def taux_act(t,m):
    if m < 365:
        taux = ((1 + t * m)/360)**(365/m)-1
    else:
        taux = t

df['taux'] = taux_act(df['Taux moyen pondéré'],df['maturite'])
```

```
Date d'échéance        datetime64[ns]
Transaction                    object
Taux moyen pondéré             object
Date de la valeur      datetime64[ns]
maturite              timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I have two columns : Taux moyen pondéré and maturite.The column "maturite" is the difference between two dates in my DataFrame.I want to add a column in my DataFrame that calculate the yield "taux_act"function that i defined

Comment: Is there a question?  Please update the main question post accordingly.

Comment: @S3DEV I must calculate the yield "taux_act" from two columns of my dataframe as below.and i got this error : TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Comment: Right. `t` is some object type and `m` is Timedelta. So your comparison doesn't make sense. What would `'0 days 05:34:54' < 365` mean? Then after that what would `((1 + something * '0 days 05:34:54') / 360) ** (365 / '0 days 05:34:54') -1` evaluate to?

Comment: @ Henry Ecker  t is not a date for me. t is a float' 0.00%' which is df['Taux moyen pondere'] when i called the function

Comment: Date d'échéance Transaction Taux moyen pondéré Date de la valeur  maturite
0       2019-04-14     104,47             2,300 %          2019-03-18                  27 days
1       2019-05-20      71,28             2,333 %        2019-03-11                    70 days
2       2019-06-17     183,19             2,337 %        2019-03-14                   95 days
This my dataframe

Comment: @HenryEcker ? ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.